# @pnp/sp ensure works with my sandbox's workbench, but fails when deployed

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I am using @pnp/sp to ensure a list exists:

```
public getLocations(): Promise<ILocation[]> {
console.log("LocationServices | getLocations | fired");

return sp.web.lists.ensure(DELIVERY_BOARD_NAME)
    .then((ler: ListEnsureResult): Promise<any> => {
        console.log("LocationServices | getLocations | ensure complete");

        if (ler.created) {
            let batchCreate = sp.web.createBatch();
            ler.list.fields.inBatch(batchCreate).addText('Abbreviation');
            return batchCreate.execute()
                .then((): Promise<any> => {
                    let batchDisplay = sp.web.createBatch();
                    let view = ler.list.defaultView;
                    view.fields.inBatch(batchDisplay).add('Abbreviation');
                    return batchDisplay.execute();
                })
                .then(() => ler.list.items.select("Title", "Abbreviation", "Id").get());
        } else {
            return ler.list.items.select("Title", "Abbreviation", "Id").get();
        }
    });
}
```

Works great when I gulp serve and play with in in my sandbox's workbench.  When I `gulp bundle --ship` and `gulp package-solution --ship` and deploy it to our tenant, its failing when it calls for the list:

```
LocationServices | getLocations | fired
/sites/deployedSite/SitePages/_api/web/lists:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
my-web-part_296a730be8d03ebb8e5ca894f4c1a0a1.js:118 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable: [404]  ::> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at my-web-part_296a730be8d03ebb8e5ca894f4c1a0a1.js:118
```

Clicking on the `my-web-part_296a730be8d03ebb8e5ca894f4c1a0a1.js:118` goes to a really long string that I can't make sense of (pretty sure its mimified)

In the network tab, I got 2 404's:

[image]

I'm assuming the first is checking to see if the list exists, and when it doesn't it sends a 404 (not found) back.

The second 404 is when pnp is trying to create the list:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't setting up `sp`:

```
public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    return super.onInit().then(_ => {
        sp.setup({
            spfxContext: this.context
        });
    });
}
```

It was answered on

> The global var exists on the workbench but not in the closure of the loaded web part.